# App using place autocomplete crashes with java null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, nullpointerexception, adb

I am literally using the code for place autocomplete that android developer guises has given us. https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete. The only thing I have done differently is change the signs on my parameters from ;= to =.  My app keeps crashing on the third letter you type in. Another thing that Ive changed is that

```
      DeviceMonitor: Adb rejected connection to client '16930': closed
```

so in order to make this app run ive been launching the activity instead of the usual app . I changed the settings under run --> edit configurations. The app starts running then when i type it crashes,,

Lastly I debugged my app. I can see that the place autocomplete is working. It collects 5 addresses from the three characters ive typed in and the it gives into looper. java and displays these three messages.

```
msg.callback=java.lang.NullPointerException;
msg.what=java.lang.NullPointerException;
msg.target=java.lang.NullPointerException;
```

My logcat only shows me this

```
03-18 18:41:23.681  15138-15138/com.example.anusha.app I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
03-18 18:41:34.842  15138-15174/com.example.anusha.app W/ActivityThread﹕ ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
03-18 18:41:36.244  15138-15138/com.example.anusha.app I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3869936)
OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.11.SPL
Build Date: 01/17/14 Fri
Local Branch:
Remote Branch:
Local Patches:
Reconstruct Branch:
03-18 18:41:44.181  15138-15138/com.example.anusha.app I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
03-18 18:41:44.201  15138-15138/com.example.anusha.app I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
 03-18 18:41:44.201  15138-15138/com.example.anusha.app W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 534: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
03-18 18:41:44.201  15138-15138/com.example.anusha.app I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
03-18 18:41:44.201  15138-15138/com.example.anusha.app W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 556: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
```